# Custom markup language JSON to vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, markup

I'm in process of learning Vue and i was building a simple wiki page. Raw article data are JSON file written in a custom markup. For instance, the following markup:
`The ''sun'' is {r=black black}`
should be "compiled" in this way:
`<p>The <b>sun</b> is <Ref path="/black">black</p>`
I'm able to do this with regexp and string manipulation, but i can't use that string as template option since it works with only static inputs. If it was only html i could've used v-html directive or something else related.
My template fetch the JSON file and parse my custom markup according to the criteria i've choosen. What it gets out of it, is a string (Vue markup) can't be assigned to 'template' options since it accept only static string and doesn't recognize any variable.

I tried assigning the template options a vue markup compiled or using a runtime-compiler. Maybe i'm wrong. How could i do?

Comment: what's the problem you removed the checkbox. any better solution?

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev the solution works perfectly, i put back the checkbox, I don't know why it removed itself

Comment: no problem, was wondering, and i need your vote, really)

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev I would love to thank you with my vote but I joined stack overflow yesterday and I don't have enough reputation to vote

Comment: I'll wait )))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile a vue template with `compile()` and insert into your current template with `<Component>`. Also we need to change alias 'vue' import to 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js' in vite.config.js to enable this feature.

[image]

Changed files from `npm create vue@latest`:

App.vue

```
<script setup>

import { ref, compile } from 'vue';

const msg = ref('Hello world!');
const component = ref(compile('<HelloWorld :msg="msg"></HelloWorld>'));

</script>

<template>
    <main>
        <Component :is="component" :msg="msg"></Component>
    </main>
</template>
```

main.js

```
import './assets/main.css'

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'


const app = createApp(App);
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
app.component('HelloWorld', HelloWorld);
app.mount('#app')
```

vite.config.js

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        }
    }
})
```