# Inserting HTML at specific location on page without extra div element?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm looking for a way to insert an HTML string at a specific location on my page without adding an additional  element. Currently, I'm using the following code:

```
<template v-html="myHtml">
</template>
```

However, this approach doesn't seem to work. I understand that I need to use an HTML element, such as a div, but I want to avoid adding an additional div to my markup. How can I achieve this without the need for an extra div?

It's worth noting that the solution should support server-side rendering (SSR), which means I can't rely on using document or any similar client-side methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should compile your HTML into a component and insert it into a template with `<Component>`:

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components

Exactly how to do that step-by-step I've described here:

[Custom markup language JSON to vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76546999/custom-markup-language-json-to-vue)

Answer (score 0):

As Alexander suggested, You can use a technique called [`dynamic component rendering`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components). This allows you to insert the HTML at the desired location without adding an extra div.

Example **:**

```
<template>
  <component :is="myHTMLComponent"></component>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      myHTMLComponent: null,
      myHtml: '<h3>This is HTML string</h3>'
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    // Create a component with the provided HTML string.
    const HTMLComponent = {
      template: this.myHtml
    };

    this.myHTMLComponent = HTMLComponent;
  }
};
</script>
```