# Async definition & compiling of VueJS component template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I have an application that consists of two parts:

1. Low-Code Editor to define a configuration for a Dashboard UI
2. The UI which renders said confguration.

We want to provide an open ended option in the low-code editor, for users to define their own Vue Component, pass this to our UI (which we do via socket.io) and render accordingly.

This means that, given a string arriving on the socket, e.g.:

```js
<div>{{ myvar }}</div>
<div v-if="myvar">MyVar is true</div>
```

I then want to render said content as aprt of a Vue Component.

The "simple" option would be `v-html`, but this doesn't allow for parsing of the `v-` or `{{ }}`.

I have also been trying variations with `defineComponent`, `defineAsyncComponent`, `<component :is="">` but all to no avail. I've also been searching Vue-based in-browser editors on GitHub, trying to understand how they work, as I imagine they're solving this issue, but can't make sense of it.

I have a playground with the suggested approach [here](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9Uk1rwzAM/SvCl7RQmkNvIS3so9CNfbEVdvElJErnzrGN7XQZpf99stNkO2yDkER6T9J7so/swpj5oUWWsdyVVhi/4ko0RlsPRyh1Y4TEGVis4QS11Q0kxE644gq7yKqwLlpJbK4AVNFgBskWnRdqd/1JsSg32/u7ZBZgh741MDFWGzftK4CGKOfBY2Nk4RGWYdjkPHmS5JU4rDYopYZXbWWVpyGRTKd9saWOVg2tYGzTx6fwoRc9eTrao2CgUQRwRbO0QuUzyMPc+A+ZcEvOxn5slacjSGV5OvZgM+YduajFbr53WtEuox7Ozi7so/GCXHKWDUo5K8jSx23Medti3E+secPy/Zf83nUhx9mTRYf2QJJGzBd2h76H1y8P2NH/CDa6aiWx/wGf0WnZBo097bJVFcn+wYtqb+K9oIPdunXnUbnBVBAaVx35nNEVCUv9y/q33MV8MRwRO30BrlvaAQ==) where you can see it's not working. This same behaviour is what I see when running locally. It just renders `<!-- -->` into the HTML.

Any advice most appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom markup language JSON to vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76546999/custom-markup-language-json-to-vue)

Comment: I had tried that approach, and setup a playground [here](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9Uk1rwzAM/SvCl7RQmkNvIS3so9CNfbEVdvElJErnzrGN7XQZpf99stNkO2yDkER6T9J7so/swpj5oUWWsdyVVhi/4ko0RlsPRyh1Y4TEGVis4QS11Q0kxE644gq7yKqwLlpJbK4AVNFgBskWnRdqd/1JsSg32/u7ZBZgh741MDFWGzftK4CGKOfBY2Nk4RGWYdjkPHmS5JU4rDYopYZXbWWVpyGRTKd9saWOVg2tYGzTx6fwoRc9eTrao2CgUQRwRbO0QuUzyMPc+A+ZcEvOxn5slacjSGV5OvZgM+YduajFbr53WtEuox7Ozi7so/GCXHKWDUo5K8jSx23Medti3E+secPy/Zf83nUhx9mTRYf2QJJGzBd2h76H1y8P2NH/CDa6aiWx/wGf0WnZBo097bJVFcn+wYtqb+K9oIPdunXnUbnBVBAaVx35nNEVCUv9y/q33MV8MRwRO30BrlvaAQ==) where you can see it's not working

Comment: it says clearly: Runtime compilation is not supported in this build of Vue. Use "vue.esm-browser.js" instead.
 at <Repl>; so you should either fix the import map in vue playground or build it with Vite. the approach works

Comment: I'm using the correct version of vue locally, and it still wasn't working, I'm also not using Vite.

I have now managed to get a solution and will post it. Thanks for the pointer though, definitely helped get me to the answer!

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was two-fold:

##### Config Changes

Add `runtimeCompiler: true` to the `vue.config.json`. Vue doesn't include the compile functionality by default, but doesn't complain when you do try to use it.

##### Component Changes

This is a working example component. Note the removal of the `<template></template>` from the file entirely, and dependency on the `return` of the `setup` to define the content to render.

I also needed to utilise `h` and it's ability to pass a Component object definition. Importantly, define the `props` that the child component should take, and then, pass the respective values for these properties as the second argument to the `h()` function.

```
<script>

import { h } from 'vue'

export default {
    name: 'ExampleTemplate',
    props: {
        msg: { type: Object, required: true }
    },
    setup (props) {
        return () => h({
            props: ['msg'],
            template: '<div>msg: {{ msg }}</div>'
        }, {
            msg: props.msg
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

I could then, in my particular case, replace the string passed to `template` with the response from my socket.io message, where the content is defined server-side.